# Use epsilon-delta definition of limit to establish the following: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I understand that my solution here is probably not the most efficient (My professor's solution is "cleaner") but it is how my mind attacked the problem.  I have been losing lots of points for minor details that I've been unable to see.  Does the following proof hold?  Am I making any major (or minor) errors?

\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{3}\right|&\leq\left|\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}\right|+\left|\frac{1}{3}\right|<\epsilon~~~\mbox{(by triangle inequality)}\\
&\implies\left|\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}\right|+\frac{1}{3}<\epsilon\\
&\implies\left|\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}\right| < \epsilon-\frac{1}{3}\\
&\implies \frac{1}{2} < \epsilon-\frac{1}{3}~~~~\mbox{(Because, }\sqrt{x}~\mbox{only a real number when } x\geq 0.)\\
&\implies 1<2(\epsilon-\frac{1}{3})\\
&\implies \left|x-1\right|<2\epsilon-\frac{2}{3}=\delta~~~~\mbox{(Because, choosing }x~s.t.~0<x<2\implies~-1<x-1<1)\\
\end{align*}
$\therefore \left|x-1\right|<\delta\implies\left| \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{3}\right|<\epsilon$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: When you apply the triangle inequality on line 1 of your argument, you have lost the game: if $0 < \epsilon < 1/3$, you cannot make $|\ldots| + |1/3| < \epsilon$.

Comment: You need to show that for **any** $\epsilon > 0$, you can have $|\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{3}| < \epsilon$ if $x$ is close to $1$. It is true that it would suffice to show $|\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}| + |\frac{1}{3}| < \epsilon$, but this approach will immediately fail for any $\epsilon < 1/3$.

Comment: Your proof doesn't work.  If $\varepsilon$ is small, then $\delta \lt 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I'll study over it and comment again later, I'm still confused but can't formulate a coherent question yet.

Comment: @RobArthan I thought $\delta$ statement implies the $\epsilon$ statement, so isn't it possible that $\epsilon>\frac{1}{3}$ for any $\delta>0$?...$\delta$ is arbitrarily small....then $\epsilon=(\delta+\frac{2}{3})(\frac{1}{2})$ which is always greater than $\frac{1}{3}$.  I'm sure what you're saying is right, but I don't see it.

Comment: Just Re-read the definition and I've been missing the detail "given any $\epsilon$>0$, there exists..." hence I must be able to get \epsilon arbitrarily close to zero as well.  Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: @RobArthan I think the triangle inequality can still work, but I shouldn't have subtracted from $\epsilon$.  I should have dropped it. $\left|\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}\right|+\frac{1}{3}<\epsilon\implies \left|\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}\right|<\epsilon$ finishes out to $\delta=\inf(1,2 \epsilon$).

Comment: Your approach puts some sort of restriction on values of $\epsilon$. Thus the working in your question makes $\epsilon>1/3$.

Comment: A more fundamental problem (in the approach in your question as well as in last comment)  is that you replace the inequality $|f(x) - L|<\epsilon$ with say $g(x) <\epsilon $ in order to do some simplification but you lose the chain of implication. Your new inequality should always be such that $g(x) <\epsilon\implies |f(x) - L|<\epsilon $ and not the other way round $|f(x) - L|<\epsilon \implies g(x) <\epsilon $. The original inequality as per definition is a target, the final in a chain of logical implications.

Comment: You can think of the target inequality as a goal to be achieved and the intermediate inequality as one of ways to achieve that goal. You can't change the goalpost itself.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Are you talking about the original question as posted or the answer I posted below?  I agree with your comments for the original post.  I think I've resolved it, in what I've provided below.

Comment: Your answer below has the problem of changing the goalpost. Your new inequality does not imply old one.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I think I understand what you're saying.  The new approach below (dropping the $+\frac{1}{3}$ in this case doesn't imply that the orginal $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ (although in this particular case it works because of square root, $x\geq 0$.  Minimum value for $|f(x)-L|=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{6}$ and $|\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}|<\epsilon\implies |\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{3}|<\epsilon$.  Or, are you saying that I must make purely algebraic path to $|x-1|<\delta(\epsilon)$?  I appreciate you help.  These are the nuances of epsilon-delta proofs that I keep messing up I think.

Comment: @C-Web: Well the idea is to analyze the difference $|f(x) - L|$ in detail and figure out how it sort of depends on the difference $|x-a|$. There may be such a dependence although not a very direct one. In such a case there is hope that $L$ may be the desired limit. If there is no such dependence then we are almost sure that $L$ is not the desired limit.

Comment: @C-Web: you on the other hand remove the $L$ itself which is crucial to the question "is $L$ the desired limit?".

Comment: @C-Web: also note that there are no nuances in most common $\epsilon, \delta$ proofs rather they are simple strategies to bound some expressions. One has to treat these things as trivial rather than deep.

Answer (score 3):

What you did cannot possibly work. Since, for any $x\in\mathbb R$,$$\left\lvert\frac1{2+\sqrt x}\right\rvert+\frac13\geqslant\frac13,$$ if $\varepsilon\in\left(0,\frac13\right)$, then there is no $\delta>0$ such that$$\lvert x-1\rvert<\delta\implies\left\lvert\frac1{2+\sqrt x}\right\rvert+\frac13<\varepsilon.$$Note that\begin{align}\left\lvert\frac1{2+\sqrt x}-\frac13\right\rvert&=\left\lvert\frac{1-\sqrt x}{3\left(2+\sqrt x\right)}\right\rvert\\&\leqslant\frac{\left\lvert\sqrt x-1\right\rvert}6\\&=\frac{\left\lvert\left(\sqrt x-1\right)\left(\sqrt x+1\right)\right\rvert}{6\left(\sqrt x+1\right)}\\&\leqslant\frac{\left\lvert x-1\right\rvert}6.\end{align}So, for each $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta=6\varepsilon$.

Comment: Just Re-read the definition and I've been missing the detail "given any $\epsilon$>0$, there exists..." hence I must be able to get \epsilon arbitrarily close to zero as well.  Thank you all for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to relate $\displaystyle \left| \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{3} \right|$ with $|x-1|$ in a proper way:

$\displaystyle \left| \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{3} \right| = \left| \frac{1 - \sqrt{x}}{3(2+\sqrt{x})} \right| = \left| \frac{1-x}{3(1+\sqrt{x})(2+\sqrt{x})} \right| \leq \frac{|x-1|}{3\cdot1\cdot2} = \frac{|x-1|}{6}$ so for a given

$\epsilon > 0$, choosing $\delta=\epsilon$ gives you for $0<|x-1|<\delta = \epsilon$,

$\displaystyle \left| \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{3} \right| \leq \frac{|x-1|}{6} < \frac{\delta}{6} = \frac{\epsilon}{6} < \epsilon$.

Comment: That's the exact approach my professor took.  I agree that this is cleaner, but I'm trying to understand what in my thinking (or understanding of delta - epsilon) is flawed.

Comment: Just Re-read the definition and I've been missing the detail "given any $\epsilon$>0$, there exists..." hence I must be able to get \epsilon arbitrarily close to zero as well.  Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: I am happy to hear that you comprehend the definition of limit and meaning of "for all $\epsilon>0$" so well. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following salvages the initial strategy while still holding true to the mathematical principals of epsilon-delta definition of limits.  Feedback welcome.  Please let me know if I have made another error.  I posted this as an answer so that the original question could remain for reference.

\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{3}\right|&\leq\left|\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}\right|+\left|\frac{1}{3}\right|<\epsilon~~~\mbox{(by triangle inequality)}\\
&\implies\left|\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}\right| < \epsilon~~~~(|a|+|b|<\epsilon\implies|a|<\epsilon)\\
&\implies \frac{1}{2} < \epsilon~~~~\mbox{(Because, }\sqrt{x}~\mbox{only a real number when } x\geq 0.~\mbox{Hence, } \delta\leq 1)\\
&\implies 1<2\epsilon\\
&\implies |x-1|\leq\delta\implies-1\leq x-1\leq 1\implies 0\leq x\leq 2\\
&~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(\delta\mbox{-neighborhood of }x~\mbox{is }1~\mbox{or less.})\\
&\implies \left|x-1\right|<2\epsilon=\delta~~~~\mbox{(Because, }|x-1|\leq 1)\\
\end{align*}
$\therefore~\forall~\delta=\inf(1,2\epsilon),~\left|x-1\right|<\delta\implies\left| \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{3}\right|<\epsilon$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Are you really sure that if $0<|x-1|<\delta=\min(1,2\epsilon)\implies |1/(2+\sqrt{x})|<\epsilon$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I'm inclined to say yes here.If $2\epsilon > 1$, then $\epsilon >\frac{1}{2}$ and $-\frac{1}{3}<f(x)-L<\frac{1}{2}$ holds.  If $2\epsilon<1$, then $\epsilon<1/2$ and since $-2\epsilon<|x-1|<2\epsilon$ then $1-2\epsilon<x<1+2\epsilon$ ~~~OOOHHH!  I see what you mean!.~~~~  We used the triangle inequality a good bit in complex analysis.  Is it generally a mistake to use it in real variable analysis?  Or, is it just one of those situational recognition things where sometimes it fits and sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: the problem is not the triangle inequality. It is just a tool and you need to understand how to use a tool to achieve your goal. Sometime you may not a specific tool at all. Start by analyzing the difference $|f(x) - L|=\dfrac{|\sqrt{x} - 1|}{3(2+\sqrt{x})}$ and see if we can make it small by assuming that $|x-1|$ small. Usage of inequalities in analysis proofs in more about understanding them in words rather symbol manipulation.

Comment: Thus for example one can write the above expression as $\dfrac{|x-1|}{3(1+\sqrt{x})(2+\sqrt{x})}$. And now things are much clearer. If one assumes $|x-1|$ small then the numerator becomes small and this ensures that the overall fraction is small provided we ensure denominator does not become too small. So the problem shifts now to analysis of denominator. And we have to ensure that it does not become too small. But this part is obvious as denominator anyway exceeds $3\cdot 2\cdot 1=6$. You can now understand why $\delta=6\epsilon$ will work as expected.